# Error convert view using RazorPDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorpdf

I build this format of link: http://localhost:33333/Invoices/Reports?format=pdf

When I run this shows this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType9`11[Webb.Models.Faktury,System.Int32,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.Single],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Single],System.Nullable`1[System.Single],System.Nullable`1[System.Single]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Webb.Models.Faktury]'.

View:

```
@model List<Webb.Models.Faktury>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Html Report</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>User Name</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Lucky Number</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.FAK_Id</td>
                <td>................</td>
                <td>@item.FAK_Numer</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
// Setup sample model
            var pro = (from a in db.Fakturies
                       join b in db.Wierszes on a.FAK_Id equals b.WIE_Fkid
                       join c in db.Produkties on b.WIE_Pid equals c.PRO_Id

                       select new
                       {
                           a,
                           a.FAK_Id,
                           a.FAK_Numer,
                           a.FAK_DataS,
                           a.FAK_TerminZ,
                           a.FAK_Rabat,
                           b.WIE_Ilosc,
                           c.PRO_Nazwa,
                           c.PRO_CenaN,
                           c.PRO_CenaB,
                           c.PRO_Vat
                       });


            pro = pro.Where(a => a.FAK_Id == 6);

            // Output to Pdf?
            if (Request.QueryString["format"] == "pdf")
                return new PdfResult(pro, "Reports");

            return View(pro);
        }
```

What should I do to export success view to pdf with data from database?

--EDIT 1:

```
public ActionResult Reports(int? id)
        {
            // Setup sample model
            var pro = (from a in db.Fakturies
                       join b in db.Wierszes on a.FAK_Id equals b.WIE_Fkid
                       join c in db.Produkties on b.WIE_Pid equals c.PRO_Id
                       select a);

            pro = pro.Where(a => a.FAK_Id == id);

            var vm = new PrintViewModel();
            vm.Fakturies = pro;  //assuming pro is already loaded with the above code.
            vm.Wierszes = db.Wierszes;


            if (Request.QueryString["format"] == "pdf")
                return new PdfResult(vm, "Reports");

            return View(vm);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is strongly typed to a collection of `Faktury`. But from your action method you are passing a collection of annonymous objects.

Change your LINQ expression code to do a projection using the `Faktury` class.

```
var pro = (from a in db.Fakturies
                   join b in db.Wierszes on a.FAK_Id equals b.WIE_Fkid
                   join c in db.Produkties on b.WIE_Pid equals c.PRO_Id
                   select a);

pro = pro.Where(a => a.FAK_Id == 6);

 if (Request.QueryString["format"] == "pdf")
      return new PdfResult(pro.ToList(), "Reports");

return View(pro);
```

If you need to pass more information than the list of Fakturties, you may create a view model with the properties you need.

```
public class PrintViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<Faktury> Fakturies {set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<Wiersz> Wierszes {set;get;}  

  public PrintViewModel()
  {
    this.Fakturies = new List<Faktury>();
    this.Wierszes = new List<Wiersz>();
  }
}
```

and in your action method, create an object of this, assign the property values and send to the view.

```
var vm=new PrintViewModel();
vm.Fakturies=pro;  //assuming pro is already loaded with the above code.
vm.Wierszes =db.Wierszes;
return View(vm);
```

Now make sure that your view is strongly typed to this new view model

```
@model PrintViewModel
<h3>Fatturies</h3>
@foreach(var f in Model.Fakturies)
{ 
  <p>@f.FAK_Numer</p>
}
<h3>Wierszes</h3>
@foreach(var f in Model.Wierszes)
{ 
  <p>@f.Name</p>
}
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but:

1) what to do if i want to display some field from other tables? For example column WIE_Ilosc from db.Wierszes?
2) what to do when i have a duplicate result (result from sql query)?

ID Numer
6 FS/6/6/2016
6 FS/6/6/2016

I want to show only one.

Comment: I have error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Webb.Models.Faktury]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Webb.Models.PrintViewModel'.
when I run from this link format http://localhost:65294/Invoices/Reports/6?format=pdf

Comment: From your action method, you should pass the object of the `PrintViewModel`(**as clearly shown in my answer**) to the view.

Comment: Sorry, I am begginer. Look at my edit1. When I use with if clause, it doesn't work - the document does not display correctly. How do I delete this line, it works but is in pdf format

Comment: I do not know what your PdfResult class looks like. So i cannot tell you why it is not working.

Comment: only this line convert html view to pdf:

if (Request.QueryString["format"] == "pdf")
                return new PdfResult(vm, "Reports");

Comment: Result of field from table Wierszes are all records, but not this which are only connected with the table Faktury

Comment: My answer is to show you how to pass data from different table/data sets. you can change the code where we are reading all data to a linq join statement as needed.

Comment: Can you explain how Can I do this?